# How to Restore Java on Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, jdk, java

I tried to install Java 7 on my Macbook running Snow Leopard following the instruction detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536667/how-to-install-java-jdk-7-on-snow-leopard/18788474#18788474

I did everything to the letter with PackageMaker, and it seemed to install successfully, but now when I try to open a .jar, I get this in the console:

[image]

I can't run Feed The Beast's launcher .jar, and Java applets aren't working either:

[image]

Minecraft's launcher.jar won't run either, but the .app launcher runs fine, and Minecraft itself works just fine when started from there.

The version of Java according to `java -version` is `java version "1.7.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)`

I don't know a whole bunch about java, so I have no clue what this means. The only thing I can think of doing to fix it is restoring to a three-week old backup and moving over all the newer files manually.

Is there any way of re-installing java so I don't have to restore the entire drive? Alternatively, would re-installing Snow Leopard from the disk work without messing with non-system files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 7 requires Mac OS 10.7 (Lion) according to: [The Oracle Java install page for Mac OS X](http://java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml)

Uninstall instructions are here: http://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

If you're going to stay on Snow Leopard you should be able to restore Java 6 from the Software Update application.